# Writing a save method in php for a general api

Tags: php, oop, function, abstraction

I have recently been playing with some very general OOP Concepts and learning to abstract my code. For this purpose I wrote a general car api that saves data to an array.

The problem is I can add, list, delete and find the data but when it comes to editing....well that's difficult.

I wrote a find method that would do:

```
public function find($car){
    if(in_array($car, $this->_carArray)){
        return $this->_carArray[$car];
    }

    return false;
}
```

So now I can find and return the car object. Which is just an array such as:

```
array(
 'type' => 'gas',
 'make' => 'some-make'
 'model' => 'some-model',
 'year' => '2005'
);
```

Then I can use a custom __set() method I wrote to set say a new type, or a new model or even add an odometerReading.

The problem is, when I do all that, I am left with an array - How do I save that data using a save method?

I hope I gave enough info.

Comment: Abstracting away from objects is not an OOP concept.  If you want to abstract the persistence then the Repository should be handling the marshalling/unmarshalling and the client code should be dealing with objects.

Comment: that has nothing to do with my problem. but thanks.

Comment: I'm pretty sure it does.  "I am left with an array"(of primitives) <- This shouldn't happen in OOP if the structure corresponds to an object from the domain model anywhere but at the lowest levels.  It sounds like your chasing the wrong kind of abstraction. If you want a more dynamic structure then you should use something like an StdObject. If you want to work with arrays through verticals then you should redefine your question outside of an OOP context.

Comment: I cant accept any of these as answers please some one post an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Abstracting away from objects is not an OOP concept. If you want to abstract the persistence then the Repository should be handling the marshalling/unmarshalling and the client code should be dealing with objects